# Trouble connecting to Oracle XE running in Centos Virtual Box

Tags: oracle-xe

I have a centos vm that I run using virtual box. I installed Oracle XE on this vm, and am now having trouble connecting to it from my SQL Developer running on my host machine (OS X).

Things I checked:

- I can ssh into centos fine.
- When I run nmap on the host machine while the centos vm is running I see port 1521 open. (`nmap -sT -O localhost`)
- I can run `telnet localhost 1521` and it connects fine.
- `tnsping xe` on the centos vm returns `OK` message
- I can connect as my user using sqlplus on the centos vm
- I have port forwarding setup in VirtualBox to forward requests on port 1521 to centos.

What I cannot do is connect using SQLDeveloper on the mac.

Here is my listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

and my tnsnames.ora:

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

I am not sure what else I am missing, or what other troubleshooting steps I can take to resolve this.